# loss function and accuracy are not changing keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

My Keras model is not learning anything and I can't figure out why. the probleme that the loss and accuracy values are unchangerd during the training epoches. i have tried to increase the learning rate but it did not work, i have tried also to change the optmizers but i did not have an improvement. 
Complete code follows:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras import backend as K
import glob, os
import keras
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *

dataset = pd.read_csv('meta_sign_1-8_means.csv')


X = dataset.iloc[:,1:101].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,0].values

order = list(range(0,len(y)))
random.shuffle(order)

#print(order)

X = X[order,:]
y = y[order]

print(X[1,:])
#print(y[1:10])

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
encoded_Y=encoder.transform(y)
y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
X = X.astype('float32')

model= Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=90,input_shape = (100,)))
#model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units=100))
#model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(402, activation='softmax'))
optm = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(optimizer=optm,loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y,batch_size=512,nb_epoch=1000,verbose=1)
```

the training output:

```
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0024
Epoch 38/1000
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0023
Epoch 39/1000
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0024
Epoch 40/1000
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0025
Epoch 41/1000
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0023
Epoch 42/1000
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0023
Epoch 43/1000
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0024
Epoch 44/1000
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0024
Epoch 45/1000
401999/401999 [==============================] - 1s 3us/step - loss: 5.9965 - accuracy: 0.0023
```

the dataset is available here :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rV1nHMFXh18Z1dDhlWJdWdC87UOKU0q5/view?usp=sharing
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Comment: What does `print(X.shape, y.shape)` give, when you insert that line right above`model = Sequential()`?

Comment: @FrederikBode when add the print shape of X and y i got : (401999, 100) (401999, 402)

Comment: The logic in your code looks good to me, correct loss_function, no super weird model. I'm just going to shoot some ideas at you if that's OK. The first thing I would try is switching from `keras` to `tf.keras`, it's the same but it's all `tensorflow` it just makes sense. Start with only a single `tf.keras.layers.Dense`, because the accuracy should at least _change_ (up or down doesn't matter yet, it should _change_ first). Check if your `LabelEncoder` is working as expected (i.e. it doesn't output the same value for everythin). Update me when you tested these things, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @FrederikBode I did what you have recommended, but without success. as you can see I have edited the code to use `tf.keras` instead of `keras` and I let only one dense layer, the loss value neither changer up or down, and finally, I added a line to print the values of the encoded vectors. the log seems good.   `for e in y: print(numpy.argmax(e, axis=None, out=None))`

Comment: I have added a log to show me the weights of layer zero at the beginning of each epoch. the weights do not change over the epochs and they show NAN values.

Comment: Finally, I have found the source of the problem, it was my CSV file which contains 'nan' values.